# Query in CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm currently making a CoreData based recipes app where there are categories and recipes belonging to a certain category.
My problem is i don't know how to only fetch the the correct recipes. For example when pressing "pasta dishes" you go to a vc with all the pasta dishes recipes.

I have successfully fetch the data for the categories and i have passed the data onto the recipeVC. But i don't know how to query correct. I have tried this:

```
    var category: Category!
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    func fetchAndSetResults() {

        do {
            let request = Recipe.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Recipe>
            let pred = NSPredicate(format: "category CONTAINS %@", category.name!)
            request.predicate = pred
            self.recipes = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            
        }
    }
```

In categoriesVC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ToRecipes" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? RecipeVC {
                destination.category = selectedCategory
            }
        }
    }
```

In my Recipe entity i have an attribute 'category' : string

Thanks!

Comment: Have you created relationships between the 2 entities?

Comment: No, I haven't. Is this the way to do it? And if so -  how? :) @JoakimDanielson

Comment: It's a very common thing to do and part of what you should know as a Core Data developer. Fortunately there shouldn't be a problem to find tutorials and articles on the topic. Once you have researched and implemented them you can skip the whole fetch request and predicate and simply do something similar to `self.recipes = category.recipes`

Comment: Yeah I read the documentations and i have successfully created a relationship between the two. When I'm typing your code it says Cannot assign value of type 'Recipe?' to type '[Recipe]' how do i fix this? @JoakimDanielson Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you. have a to-one relationship from category to recipe, I assume it should be a to-many relationship

Comment: Now that i have changed that it says Cannot assign value of type 'NSSet?' to type '[Recipe]' @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from @JoakinDanielson and some research I found the solution.
I am used to working with Firebase so CoreData was new to me.
First i created an inverse relationship between the two entities.
Then i changed the type of the relationship to "To Many"
Then in the Category extension I changed

```
@NSManaged public var recipes: NSSet?
```

to

```
 @NSManaged public var recipes: [Recipe]?
```

Then when the user is creating a recipe this piece of code

```
  category.addToRecipes(recipe)
```

now the recipe is created and belongs to the chosen category.

And now all there is to do is when populating your tableview - this piece of code

```
 self.recipes = category.recipes ?? [Recipe]()
```

That worked for me at least!